# Swap foreign keys in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql database with a `Users` table:

```sql
create table Users
(
    Id          varchar(255) charset utf8mb4 not null primary key,
    ProfileId   int auto_increment,
    #other fields
);
```

`ProfileId` field is used as a foreign key for many tables. E.g.:

```sql
create table Fingerprints
(
    Id        int auto_increment primary key,
    ProfileId int null,

    constraint FK_Fingerprints_Users_ProfileId
        foreign key (ProfileId) references Users (ProfileId)
);
```

I have two Users records and want to swap their ProfileIds without any other changes. How can I do it? I would prefer not to drop foreign key constrain because the database is on production and there are a lot of related tables where I have to do that.

**Update:**
The data is the following:

```
User1: ProfileId = 1,
User2: ProfileId = 2
#the other field doesn't matter
```

I want to swap their profileIds, so user1 contained user2's data from the related table by foreign key and vise versa.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What do you want to happen to the foreign key references?

Comment: Added more info

Comment: Update `Fingerprints.ProfileId` accordingly.

Comment: @Serg The problem is that I have a lot of tables where ProfileId is a foreign key, and I don't want to update all of them.

Comment: Alternatively you can update  #other fields of `users` . Not sure how they are related to other tables although.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you don't want to change the foreign key relationships (they are not defined as cascading) I would suggest that you change the other columns:

```
update users u join
       users u2
       on (u2.profileid, u.profileid) in ( (@id1, @id2), (@id2, id1) )              
    set u.id = u2.id,
        u.others = u2.others;
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. I have related tables, and I want to swap the data of the users.